# Meteor on AWS using Mup - SSL with ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, meteor, elastic-load-balancer, meteor-up

I'm migrating my Meteor app to AWS, want to use ACM issued SSL cert attached to ELB.
My current setup is:

- ELB with ACM SSL cert(verified that load balancing and HTTPS is working on simple HTTP server inside EC ubuntu machine)
- Meteor up is deployed on EC2 machine using Mup (Please see my `mup.js` which works well with SSL cert physically available from file system)

I want to stop using reverse proxy from `mup.js` config completely and let ELB run all SSL stuff. Problem is that ELB is not able to communicate with Meteor up, 
have tried different ROOT_URLs but none are working:

- EC2 Elastic IP with HTTP and HTTPS
  (i.e. ROOT_URL: 'https://my-ec2-elastic-ip.com', ROOT_URL: 'http://my-ec2-elastic-ip.com')
- ELB domain name with HTTP and HTTPS

What should I put for ROOT_URL and is it game changer in accepting requests? i.e. if I have wrong ROOT_URL, will Meteor still be able to accept incoming requests?

- Mup version: 1.4.3
- Meteor version: 1.6.1

Mup config

```js
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: 'ec2-111111.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
      username: 'ubuntu',
      pem: 'path to pem'
    }
  },
  meteor: {
    name: 'my-app',
    path: 'path',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    },
    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },
    env: {
      ROOT_URL: 'https://ec2-111111.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongo url',
    },
    dockerImage: 'abernix/meteord:node-8.9.1-base',
    deployCheckWaitTime: 30,
  },
  proxy: {
    domains: 'ec2-111111.compute-1.amazonaws.com,www.ec2-111111.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
    ssl: {
      crt: './cert.pem',
      key: './key.pem'
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, first and general issue was that I was using classic ELB, which doesn't support WebSockets and was preventing DDP connection. Newer `Application Load Balancer` which comes with WebSocket and Sticky Sessions helped. More on the diff here: https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/details/#details

Another issue more specific to my use case was having no endpoint for ELB health check, I was hiding/securing everything behind basic_auth, health check was getting `403  unauthorized` failing and not registering EC2 instance in ELB. Make sure you have endpoint for health check that returns `200 OK`, and also revisit your security groups - check out `inbound rules` and make sure ELB has access to corresponding ports to EC2 instance(80, 443 etc.).